# Gauss Quadrature Error in 2D

Tags: numerical-methods, orthogonal-polynomials, error-function, quadrature

Could someone tell me what is the error when applying the Gauss Quadrature rule in 2 dimensions? I know that for one dimension the error is

$$\frac{(n!)^{4}}{(2n+1)[(2n)!]^{3}} \cdot f(\xi)^{2n}(b-a)^{2n+1}$$

For some $a< \xi <b$.

On the other hand, what value of $\xi$ should I take between $a$ and $b$ for obtain the error? I imagine the error varies depending on the value $\xi$ that I choose.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using 1D Gauss rules applied to the iterated integrals or are you using 2D Gauss rules?

Comment: Regarding $\xi$, the error obviously does not depend on the choice of $\xi$... There exists a $\xi$ such that the error is given by a that expression but you don't get  to choose $\xi$. Normally, since we do not know the value of $xi$, we just obtain an upper bound for the error by saying that 
$$|f^{(2n)}(\xi)| \leq \sup_{x \in [a,b]}|f^{(2n)}(x)|.$$

Comment: I am integrating a function of 2 variables numerically with Gauss Quadrature Rule: $$A = \int_{xa}^{xb} \int_{ya}^{yb} F(x,y) dx dy$$. I would like to know thye error for this integral in 2D using Gauss Quadrule.  I imagine that is similar to 1D error.

Comment: I do not undertand well. Could you show me an easy example where you get an upper upper bound for the error?. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the exact rule you are using? Some Gauss rules are designed directly for 2d integrals and others are applications of 1d Gauss rules to the iterated integrals. regarding the upper bound for the error, imagine that you are integrating $f(x)=\sin x$ in some interval. You know that $|f^{(2n)}(\xi)| \leq \sup_{x \in [a,b]}|f^{(2n)}(x)| \leq 1$.

Comment: I am using Gauss-Legendre Rule. Thanks again.